# Cannot make changes to specific folder

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, file-system, aokp, file-permissions

My phone is rooted with aokp build 38 on it. It is a Verizon Galaxy Nexus (toro)

There is a folder `/sdcard/data` that I can't make any changes to. Some of my apps are trying to use this folder but are not able to because any changes to this folder fail.

I tried deleting it but was unable to. I even used `adb shell` with root access and tried to `rmdir`, but it says "Permission Denied"

I also tried to `chmod 777` to give full access to the folder, but I still was unable to make any changes to it.

I'm at a loss as of what to do to make this directory writeable again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a backup of your data first.

> every folder and file in the /sdcard/data directory is 0 bytes.

This looks like a corrupted filesystem or a defective sdcard (see correction). Especially, folders have a usual minimum size of 4.0K.

I'd suggest you to back up your data first, then check for errors:

Does "dmesg" show filesystem errors on mmcblk0 or similar?

If so try to backup, reformat sdcard (see correction) and restore or replace the faulty sdcard.

(EDIT) Correction:
The Galaxy Nexus has no SDCard but a unified EXT4 filesystem for /data that also includes /sdcard (which is symlinked to /data/media). You might solve the problem with a wipe. But that will also delete all of your /sdcard content too.

You might have luck entering recovery and adb'ing into it to fsck.ext4 your /data partition, I'm however not sure if your rom supports this command

`# boot to recovery first!

adb shell

cat /proc/partitions

 # look for the biggest one and replace the ?? accordingly

fsck.ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk???`

Here's an external report about a similar issue:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1541379

Comment: How do I get adb to recognize my device when it's in recovery?  It always says device not found.  (I feel like it should just see it, but maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: Some recoveries don't start adb internally but offer an option to do so in the menu. If adb is missing altogether you can start a different recovery temporarily: download a recovery image from https://clockworkmod.com/rommanager and boot to fastboot mode. Then execute 'fastboot boot <recovery-...img>' Adb should work until the next reboot then

Comment: I ended up just restoring to stock.  I'll reflash a custom ROM later.  I couldn't get my computer to recognize the phone when I was in recovery.  I believe your answer was correct though so I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `/data/media`, it should be the same folder as `/sdcard`. I think the files you're trying to delete might be virtual, I had this exact problem while trying to clean up in `/sdcard/Android/data` until I realized that I could also find them at the path specified.

Comment: what are 'virtual' files on a vfat/ext4 partition? the 0-byte sizes of folders are a rather clear indication of fs problems, most probably some directory inode is not accessible/parseable and gets stuck at 0 byte.#